# What's an efficient algorithm to find one unique number in a set of 1 millions numbers?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have been asked this question in an interview. In 1 million numbers, all numbers have a duplicate except for one number. How to find that one number? Which algorithm should I use to get a good time and space complexity? I got an idea to use EXOR gate but I'm still lagging in deploying that.

Comment: You are going the correct way, What is your problem exactly? Show us what have tried so far?

Comment: @Angew: "Having duplicates" doesn't mean "there are exactly two", does it? Well, I guess in the very literal sense of the word... (But not in the Stack Overflow sense! :-) )

Comment: @KerrekSB The question says "having **the** duplicate." Not to mention the fact that for XOR to work, there has to be an even number of each duplicate.

Comment: do you know anything about the numbers? signed/unsigned, data type, are they sorted to begin with, are they all the integers starting with a particular N?

Comment: Always keep in mind additional question: find two unique numbers.

Comment: Yes Angew, you are right , that is 1000001 numbers. Sorry for not mentioning that!

Comment: Mikhail, in case of finding two unique numbers xor will not work ??

Comment: Not an algorithm but a solution  : disk space and data bases (my sql) are cheap. Put numbers in to a data base table, then select where count(*) after group by self == 1. Let the data base do its work and we solve the problem :-)

Comment: example with data base doing the work http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0c8c0/1

Comment: You should ask to move your question on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/?as=1

Comment: @Kiwy He already did that, and it has since been [closed](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17750/algorithm-to-find-one-unique-number-in-one-million-and-1-numbers).

Comment: @Wipqozn well that's definitly something I don't understand all quesiton I read on golf code was that kind of question

Answer (score 29):

Use [`xor`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR) for all numbers sequentially.

For following list of numbers:

`1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1`

Let `^` represents the exclusive disjunction (or `xor`)

Then,
`1 ^ 2 ^ 3 ^ 4 ^ 3 ^ 2 ^ 1 = 4`

Comment: You should add some explanation, your solution is correct:)

Comment: System.out.println(1 ^ 1 ^ 2 ^ 3 ^ 3 ^ 3); prints 1

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev : Obviously `2 ^ 3` is `1`

Comment: this will only work if there are even number of occurrence for each value, but I think duplicate means 'two' in this case

Comment: @MadHatter but it was supposed to be 2

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev : You are doing `1 ^ 1 ^ 2 ^ 3 ^ 3 ^ 3` which has three `3s` and one `2` therefore the result will be `2 ^ 3`. For result = `2` you should use two `3s`.

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev : As *Pham Trung* mentioned in his comment, I assume duplicate means only two occurances.

Comment: This will not work for a duplicate 0. `System.out.println(33 ^ 33 ^ 7 ^ 0 ^ 0 ^ 7)` is printing 0.

Comment: To anyone posting "counterexamples" - `n ^ n = 0` so pairs of numbers cancel (as `0 ^ n = n`).  To xor a list in your head, remove all pairs (and any 0s)

Comment: All counterexamples to XOR seen so far do not meet the preconditions: all expect one have one duplicate. If 0 is the one without dup then XOR will give the right answer. If 0 is the one with dup then XOR will give also the right answer.

Comment: A brief explanation of why XOR works is to consider XOR as a modulus mod 2 operation. So for any number with even number times of occurrences in the set, XORing these numbers will give you 0. This algorithm is suitable for find numbers with odd occurrences only but not unique numbers.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    int[] a = {1, 2, 1, 2, 3};
    Arrays.sort(a);
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0 && a[i] != a[i + 1] || i == a.length -1 || a[i] != a[i - 1] && a[i] != a[i + 1]) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: that's expensive computationally

Comment: this would be expensive, nearly O(N) would be HashMap from number to occurance

Comment: This will take a lot of time.. sorting algorithm take at list O(nlogn) and you have 1 million ... too much

Comment: @TarekSalah The question says million.

Comment: @Angew sorry for that.. still big number

Comment: @Angew you are right, fixed

Comment: For int[] a = { 1, 1, 2,2, 3, 4,4 }; it still returns true so I think the if check shall be like this :                                    if (a[i] != a[i - 1] && a[i] != a[i+1])

Comment: @TarekSalah million is not that big for todays computers would do sorting in milliseconds. I think it is preferable solution because like X-OR one it is not assuming that duplicates are even

Comment: It may still miss correct value. And you should avoid mixing `||` and `&&` without extra parenthesis.

Comment: @Jarod42 can you give me an example when it breaks? set of ints

Answer (score 2):

Another simple solution: Two bitsets can be used, one for marking the existance of a number and another to mark duplication. We iterate through the array amd mark each element for existence and duplication. Then we iterate through the bitsets to find a number that is marked  for existence and but not marked for duplication.

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5 };

    BitSet bs1 = new BitSet();
    BitSet bs2 = new BitSet();

    int largestNumber = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        int number = numbers[i];
        if (bs1.get(number) == false) {
            // Mark for existence
            bs1.set(number);
        } else {
            // Mark for duplicating
            bs2.set(number);
        }

        if (number > largestNumber) {
            largestNumber = number;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= largestNumber; i++) {
        if (bs1.get(i) && !bs2.get(i)) {
            System.out.println("Non duplicating number is:  " + i);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your increase the memory complexity...

Answer (score 1):

Following may solve you problem:

Complexity: `O(N)`

```
// Assuming the duplicate are going by pair
// x ^x == 0 and x ^0 == x
int find_unique(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
    assert(v.size() % 2 == 1);

    int res = 0;
    for (auto value : v) {
        res ^= value;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Or
Complexity: `O(N log N)`

```
int find_unique(std::vector<int>& v)
{
    if (v.empty()) { throw std::runtime_error("empty vector"); }
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    auto it = std::unique(v.begin(), v.end());
    if (it == v.begin()) { throw std::runtime_error("no unique number"); }
    if (it != v.begin() + 1) { throw std::runtime_error("several unique numbers"); }
    return v[0];
}
```

or 
Complexity: `O(N log N)`

```
int find_unique(std::vector<int>& v)
{
    if (v.empty()) { throw std::runtime_error("empty vector"); }
    if (v.size() == 1) { return v[0]; }
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    if (v[0] != v[1]) { return v[0]; }

    for (int i = 1, size = v.size(); i + 1 < size; ++i) {
        if (v[i] == v[i - 1]) { continue; }
        if (v[i] == v[i + 1]) { ++i; continue; } // we may skip v[i + 1]
        return v[i];
    }
    return v.back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if we combine quicksort(search) technique and xor, we could get the fastest possible code. I am trying though, but correct me if this idea is wrong meanwhile.

BTW, this has good number of usecases though. Though the question is language agnostic, and requires clear algorithm, I am mentioning some use cases readers might find useful.

0's can be duplicate... or negative numbers...

`System.out.println(33 ^ 33 ^ 7 ^ 0 ^ 0 ^ 5 ^ 7 ^ 5);` is giving 0 (0 is a duplicate here)

Duplicates might be more than 2:

`System.out.println(1 ^ 1 ^ 2 ^ 3 ^ 3 ^ 3);` is giving 1, instead of 2...

And on and on, the question would possibly be complex than we might first think.

Answer (score 0):

For a large number of input items (as opposed to the examples with a few numbers) it should take a considerable amount of time getting the input into some data structure. I was thinking about using this necessary time as part of the computation process by putting it into a map. The value of the map will only be one for the one single number. I assume the data is correct so I omit checking for that, but if there are multiple numbers which occur only one time it will just return the first one.

There should be room for further optimization, e.g. by accessing the map by value and just look for the one which has 1. I think this could be done easily with Boost.Bimap.

```
int getSingleNumber(){

map<int, int> numbers;

for (all input items)
    {
    numbers[currentInputItem]++;
    }

for( map<int,int>::iterator ii=numbers.begin(); ii!=numbers.end(); ++ii)
{
    if ( (*ii).second == 1 ) return (*ii).first;
}
}
```